# Laravel send an ajax request with the same url

Tags: php, laravel

I have a webshop in laravel and always when I load the page the app.js make an ajax request with the same url. My app.js resource file is empty so I think this is a laravel function. Any idea why make the laravel this call and how can I turn off?

[image]

Comment: May be you have an ajax in your code, Can you show us the js file?

Comment: I tried with a totally empty app.js but same result. This is the function what call the request: J(){(y.addEventListener||"load"===event.type||"complete"===y.readyState)&&(I(),m.ready())}. This can't be my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is okay, because all your js and css files must be loaded from server tr
and app.js are not exceptions ))

Comment: The app.js was loaded before this call. This is an ajax request called in the app.js.